# You meet two arbitrary children of a married couple the odds are $50\%$ that they both have blue eyes. How many children does the family have?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I'm stuck on the following riddle: you meet two arbitrary children of a married couple the odds are $50\%$ that they both have blue eyes. How many children does the family (the married couple) have?

The possible answers are:

- A: $3$
- B: $4$
- C: $5$

Comment: What have you tried?  If you are stuck, go case by case.  Say there were $3$ kids.  Then they'd have to be $\{B,B,X\}$ where $B$ means blue-eyed and $X$ means non-blue-eyed.  Does that pattern work?  If so, you are done.  If not go on to $4$ and so on.  You should see a general way to proceed.

Comment: Note that the restriction of the choice of answers is necessary; the 50% condition is also possible to achieve in a family with 21 children.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There can't be $3$ children, since then there would be $3$ possibilities for which two children you meet, so you would need $1.5$ of those possibilities to give two blue-eyed children.

It can be $4$ (I'll leave you to work out how many of the four need to have blue eyes).

It can't be $5$. There are $10$ options for which two children you meet, so you need $5$ of these to give two blue-eyed children. But if there were $3$ blue-eyed children there would $3$ ways to meet two of them, and if there were $4$ blue-eyed children there would be $6$ ways, so you can't have exactly $5$.

So the answer must be $4$.

(edit: of course this assumes that you know the answer is one of those three options. But the next value that works mathematically is $21$, which is possible but rather unlikely.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question is from The National Science quiz from the Netherlands , question 7 https://www.nwo.nl/actueel/evenementen/nationale+wetenschapsquiz/2017